# How to identify source of React.createClass warning? React v15.6

Tags: reactjs

How can I identify the dependency that is causing the warning?

```
Warning: Accessing createClass via the main React package is deprecated, and will be removed in React v16.0....
```

I understand the changes that are coming with React v16.0. I want to help the dependency resolve the warnings but I don't know who needs help.

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "autosuggest-highlight": "^3.1.0",
    "material-ui": "next",
    "material-ui-icons": "^1.0.0-alpha.19",
    "nuka-carousel": "^2.2.1",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-helmet": "^5.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "typeface-roboto": "^0.0.35"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
    "jest-enzyme": "^3.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "^1.0.10",
    "react-test-renderer": "^15.6.1"
  },
```

Comment: Check the console for the complete warning, you should have there the exact file/line that this warning was caused at.

Comment: Ah I had to expand the warning and follow the trace. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome :)

Comment: As an FYI I found out it can also happen if you import with ES6 in the form of `import * as React from 'react'` wildcard imports are causing this issue with babel/webpack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You see next to the warning in the console the line of it. Jump to that line in the chrome-debugger, (just click on it)
2. Set a break-point there
3. Reload the page, and you'll get there
4. Next, in the debugger there is the stack tab, open it, to see all the functions path to that line.. You should be able to identify the problematic source

Comment: Thank you.. I just expanded the warning in the console and it it identified the dependency. Your method more detailed way to identify the source and other future problems I may run into

Comment: awesome, saw the comment just after I finished the answer ;)